# How to add value to select2 multi-select

Tags: php, database, laravel, jquery-select2

I need to add `{{$news->tag}}` to my select2 to displaying values by default, but seems doesn't working.

**Here is what I tried to do :**

```
      <div class="col-md-12 g-mb-30 g-mt-20" style="padding-left: 0px;padding-right: 0px">
      <label class="g-mb-10">Tags</label>
 <select class="form-control select2" multiple="multiple" value="{{$news->tag}}" name="tag[]" style="width: 100%;">
      @foreach($newNews as $tag)
                            <option value="{{ $tag->tag }}">{{ $tag->tag }}</option>
                @endforeach 
 </select>
  </div>
```

So, if in my database in `news->tag` value is `tag1, tag2` I need to displaying it by default in my select2 box.

Comment: `<option value="{{ $tag->tag }}" {{ (in_array($tag->tag,$news->tag)?'seleced':'' }}>{{ $tag->tag }}</option>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `selected` attribute

```html
<div class="col-md-12 g-mb-30 g-mt-20" style="padding-left: 0px;padding-right: 0px">
    <label class="g-mb-10">Tags</label>
    <select class="form-control select2" multiple="multiple" name="tag[]" style="width: 100%;">
        @foreach($newNews as $tag)
            <option value="{{ $tag->tag }}" @if($tag->tag == $news->tag) selected="selected" @endif >{{ $tag->tag }}</option>
        @endforeach 
   </select>
</div>
```